# Downloader extension for Chrome or Firefox that limits speed of downloads?

Tags: chrome, firefox, download-manager

I'm looking for a downloader extension for Chrome or Firefox that limits the speed of downloads.

[DownThemAll](https://www.downthemall.net/) did that perfectly until a recent version change on Firefox that made it incompatible, and now I can't find a replacement!

I'm using the latest of both; Chrome 63 and Firefox 57.

Comment: Sadly not an answer for your question for a DTA-replacement: 
But if you would switch to Waterfox, you could have both: the (nearly) most current "Firefox" and still the possibility to use classic extensions like DTA.